# Build a jar using jdk 1.3 and maven 1.0.2

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to build a jar file using jdk1.3 and maven 1.0.2. This is old java code which means I can't use a newer version of java. Below is the pom file I'm currently using:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sample.team</groupId>
<artifactId>Base</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Base</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.3</jdk.version>
    <!--jodatime.version>2.5</jodatime.version-->
    <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>Base</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>nebModule</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>com\abc\ebill\base\**\*.class</include>
                <include>com\abc\team\common\domain\**\*.class</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>

        <!-- download source code in Eclipse, best practice -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Set a compiler level -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Make this jar executable -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
              </excludes>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <!--mainClass>com.mkyong.core.utils.App</mainClass-->
                        <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
                <includes>
                    <include>**\com\abc\ebill\base\**\*.class</include>
                    <include>**\com\abc\team\common\domain\**\*.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Copy project dependency -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <!-- exclude junit, we need runtime dependency only -->
                  <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <!-- here the phase you need -->
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>nebModule</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>com\abc\ebill\base\**\*.java</include>
                                    <include>com\abc\team\common\domain\**\*.java</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

When calling: maven -X -p pom.xml jar:jar, a target workspace is created with a jar called Base and three folders: classes, test-classes, test-reports. The folders and the jar are empty. How can I compile the .java files into classes in: com\abc\ebill\base***.java and com\abc\team\common\domain***.java and add them to the jar?

Comment: Are you sure Java3 is going to run JUnit4?

Comment: Your pom does not look like a Maven 1.X POM file...furthermore if this should be built with Maven 3+ it should be cleaned up first cause there many things which should be done different...

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm trying to run this using Maven 1. Could you point out what is wrong with the pom? It's difficult to find any documentation on Maven 1

Comment: Old java code doesn't mean necessarily that you have to use old jdk.

Comment: Has this ever worked?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I changed up the pom and now the java:compile step is trying to compile the java classes but I'm running into some errors

Comment: But did it ever work?  I would consider getting a copy of Maven in the version this was used with, and make that work again before upgrading to the newest version.  You may have to manually download artifacts.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen this was never built with maven. It was previously built using ant

Comment: Why not just stay with ant then?  You can use a newer version of Java and I think you should, so you can use the newest Maven.  You just need to tell the compiler to use 1.3.  If your Java is so new that javac does not support 1.3, then tell Maven to use the eclipse compiler.